# How to run python in utf-8 in docker

Tags: python, docker, utf-8, character-encoding, locale

I produced this PoC (proof of concept) code to show a problam I am dealing with.

**Project structure:**

```
# ls -R docker_codes/
docker_codes/:
docker-compose.yml  dockerfile
```

**dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3
RUN export export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
RUN python3 -c "print (u'voil\u00e0')"
```

**docker.compose.yml**

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  app01:
    build: 
      context: .
```

**Command:** docker-compose up

**Output Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/docker-compose", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('docker-compose==1.18.0', 'console_scripts', 'docker-compose')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 71, in main
    command()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 124, in perform_command
    handler(command, command_options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 959, in up
    start=not no_start
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/compose/project.py", line 452, in up
    svc.ensure_image_exists(do_build=do_build)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/compose/service.py", line 324, in ensure_image_exists
    self.build()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/compose/service.py", line 972, in build
    all_events = stream_output(build_output, sys.stdout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/compose/progress_stream.py", line 23, in stream_output
    print_output_event(event, stream, is_terminal)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/compose/progress_stream.py", line 90, in print_output_event
    stream.write("%s%s" % (event['stream'], terminator))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe0' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The line `"RUN export export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8""` is the work around to deal with this problem but no sucess.

**SOLUTION:**

- As github from docker-compose, it is a error of old version of docker-compose, as follow link https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5678#issuecomment-365742784 . My version is docker-compose version 1.18.0, build 8dd22a9, when updated to  1.26.0, problem dissapear.
- The old version was installed from
  https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo with yum
- for a new version of docker-compose, follow: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

Comment: did you tried it with docker run command instead of compose `docker run -it --rm your_image _name`?

Answer (score 2):

`RUN export LC_ALL=es_US.UTF-8` will not be persisted in the following layer. Use native docker syntax for environment variables: `ENV LC_ALL=es_US.UTF-8`

And install `locales-all` pakage for getting internationalization support

Comment: The [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Locale#Configuration) discourages setting `LC_ALL` except when testing, and suggests setting `LANG` is the usual approach.